# Python: create a new dictionary getting values from a dictionary of nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm new to Python and to programming in general and I have some difficulties to find the right syntax for my code.

I have two lists:

```
I = [0, 1]
A = ['a', 'b']
```

Suppose to have a dictionary like this one :

```
my_dictionary = {(0, 'a'): [[0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]], (0, 'b'): [[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0], [2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0]], (1, 'a'): [[0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0], [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0]], (1, 'b'): [[2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0], [2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0]]}
```

I want to create a new dictionary like this : new_dictionary = {(0, 'a', 0, 0) : 0, (0, 'a', 0, 1) : 4, .... (1, 'b', 0, 0) : 2, ..... }

```
new_dictionary = dict()
for i in I:
    for j in A:
        for c in my_dictionary[i, j]:
            for d in c:
                new_dictionary.update(map((i, j, c, d), my_dictionary[i, j][c][d]))
```

this return me `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`

Help would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that, you are using list `c` as the index for `my_dictionary[i, j]`, `my_dictionary[i, j]` will return a list of list indices should always be an **integer** for a list.

let me explain this how you are landing here

```
for i in I
```

will return elements in `I` list  which are `0 and 1`

```
for j in A
```

will return elements in `A` list which are `'a' and 'b'`

```
for c in my_dictionary[i, j]
```

will return elements from list of list corresponding to `my_dictionary[i, j]` like for `my_dictionary[0, 'a']` it will return `[0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0] and [4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0]` so `c` will be assigned a list so when you will write this `my_dictionary[i, j][c]` this will return an error `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list` as c is a list which can't be used here for the index here for a list of list `my_dictionary[i, j]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! So I was wondering, is there a method I can use to get the inner value d and assign it to the key (i, j, c, d)?

Comment: can you be a bit more elaborative over this? what exactly you want as in your output?

Comment: As output I want to obtain a dictionary like this:   new_dictionary = {(0, 'a', 0, 0) : 0, (0, 'a', 0, 1) : 4, (0, 'a', 0, 2) : 0, (0, 'a', 0, 3) : 0, (0, 'a', 0, 4) : 3, (0, 'a', 0, 5) : 0, (0, 'a', 0, 6) : 0, (0, 'a', 1, 0) : 4, (0, 'a', 1, 1) : 0, (0, 'a', 1, 2) : 0, ... }

Comment: you can check the code here http://ideone.com/9sSBkG, do upvote if you find it helpful

Comment: Thank you @untwal ! I upvoted your answer but since I am a new member the vote is not publicly displayed ...